# Trouble parsing a string with Regular Expression in .Net

Tags: c#

I am new to regular expressions and am trying to parse a string from a website table. it contains numerous `\r`s, `\s`s and `\n`s along with upper and lower case letters, numerals, and commas.

Here is the string I am working with:

```
\r\n\t\t\t\tFri, Apr 06, 2018335167165420\r\n                                4X\r\n                            \r\n\t\t\t
```

and here is the expression I have thus far:

```
([A-Z][a-z]{2}[,]\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}[,]\s[0-9]{4}[0-9]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}\\r\\n\s*[0-9][A-Z])
```

If I eliminate the last `[0-9][A-Z]` from the expression it is successful up tp the `\n` before the number 4.

Comment: From that string, what are you expecting to return? `string.Trim()` and then split (removing empty entries) on the `\r\n` would give you two fields: `Fri, Apr 06, 2018335167165420`, `4X`

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought of trimming the string first.